# Return manager's samacountname for users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a requirement to create a CSV file of all active users from AD including the line manager attribute, however I need the line managers `sAMAccountName`, not the `cn`.  Here is what I have so far:

```psh
Get-ADUser -server server_ip -Filter { mail -like "*" -and ObjectClass -eq "user" } `
  -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=eu,DC=ad,DC=some_company,DC=com" `
  -Properties objectGUID,displayName,office,division,department,employeeNumber,
    employeeID,mobilePhone,officePhone,ipphone,title,givenName,surname,mail,
    manager,sAMAccountName |
  Export-CSV "EU_AD_Properties.csv"
```

This returns all the data I want, but gives me the line manager's `cn`, not the `samacountname`.

Any ideas?

I've tried this:

```psh
Get-ADUser -server server_ip -Filter { mail -like "*" -and ObjectClass -eq "user" } `
  -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=eu,DC=ad,DC=some_company,DC=com" `
  -Properties objectGUID,displayName,office,division,department,employeeNumber,
    employeeID,mobilePhone,officePhone,ipphone,title,givenName,surname,mail,
    @{Label="Manager";Expression={(Get-aduser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $_.Manager}.sAMAaccountName)}},
    sAMAccountName |
  Export-CSV "EU_AD_Properties.csv"
```

However this errors out.

Answer (score 12):

Here ya go
$user being the user you are querying for manager information

```
(get-aduser (get-aduser $user -Properties manager).manager).samaccountName
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't create custom properties in arguments to the `-Properties` parameter, because the current object variable `$_` doesn't contain a value at that point (or at least not the value you want). You need to do that in a `select` statement later in the pipeline, when `$_` actually holds the value you need to process. The way you try to create the custom property won't work either:

```
@{Label="Manager";Expression={(Get-aduser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $_.Manager}.sAMAaccountName)}}
```

The filter scriptblock doesn't have an attribute `sAMAccountName`. What you actually want to do is get the user object for the manager CN and retrieve its `sAMAccountName` attribute:

```
@{Label='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMAccountName}}
```

Also, you don't need the filter `ObjectClass -eq "user"`, because `Get-ADUser` will return only user objects anyway.

So your pipeline should probably look like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Server IP -Filter {mail -like "*"} -Properties * `
    -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=eu,DC=ad,DC=some_company,DC=com" |
  select objectGUID, displayName, office, division, department, employeeNumber,
    employeeID, mobilePhone, officePhone, ipphone, title, givenName, surname,
    mail, @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMAccountName}},
    sAMAccountName |
  Export-CSV "EU_AD_Properties.csv"
```

Comment: Sorry this errors with:<br/>Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
At E:\_AxiosSoftware\CUG\eu_ad_export.ps1:2 char:11

Comment: + Get-ADUser <<<<  -Server IP -Filter {mail -like "*"} -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=eu,DC=ad,DC=som_company,DC=com" | select objectGUID, displayName, office, division, department, employeeNumber, employeeID, mobilePhone, officePhone, ipphone, title, givenName, surname, mail, @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMAaccountName}}, sAMAccountName | Export-CSV "EU_AD_Properties.csv"

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server has returned the following error: inv
   alid enumeration context.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Ge
  tADUser

Comment: It returns data in the CSV but nothing for the manager.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try with a `DirectorySearcher` as suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/038e95e8-0f88-4fc3-8987-ec97c57f4867).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but there is a typo in here; It should be Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMAccountName . With the wrong name, it will return an empty string.

Comment: @williamwmy Thanks for the heads-up. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,SamAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,Manager | select Name,SamAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,@{N='Manager';E={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMAccountName}} | Export-Csv "Userdata.csv"
```

Comment: You should format this code and add an explanation as to how this answers the question.