# Convert Distinguished Name to SamAccountName without Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My machines have the original build of PowerShell v2.0, so `Get-ADUser` will not work.  I am trying to convert the `manager` property from it's `distinguishedname` to it's `SamAccountName`.

```psh
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$searcher.FindOne().Properties.manager
```

This works perfectly if I had `Get-ADUser`:

```psh
(get-aduser (get-aduser $user -Properties manager).manager).samaccountName
```

[Grabbed get-aduser statement from here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068840/powershell-return-managers-samacountname-for-users)

Comment: Installing the AD module from the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) will let you use `Get-ADUser` in PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ADS_ESCAPEDMODE_ON = 2
$ADS_SETTYPE_DN = 4
$ADS_FORMAT_X500_DN = 7
$Pathname = new-object -comobject "Pathname"
[Void] $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("EscapedMode", "SetProperty", $null, $Pathname, $ADS_ESCAPEDMODE_ON)

$searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountname=$Env:USERNAME)"
$managerDN = $searcher.FindOne().Properties["manager"]
if ( $managerDN ) {
  [Void] $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("Set", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, @($managerDN[0], $ADS_SETTYPE_DN))
  $escapedDN = $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("Retrieve", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Pathname, $ADS_FORMAT_X500_DN)
  ([ADSI] "LDAP://$escapedDN").Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]
}
```

Get the `manager` property for the current user (a distinguished name), escape it using the `Pathname` object, bind to it using the `[ADSI]` type accelerator, and retrieve the manager's `sAMAccountName` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the distinguished name to retrieve the user object that will give you the `sAMAccountName`:

```psh
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$manager  = [adsi]('LDAP://' + $searcher.FindOne().Properties.manager)
$manager.sAMAccountName
```

If the distinguished name contains special characters that would require escaping you could also use an additional ADSISearcher instead:

```psh
$searcher  = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$manager   = $searcher.FindOne().Properties.manager
$searcher2 = [adsisearcher]"(distinguishedName=$manager)"
$searcher2.FindOne().Properties.sAMAccountName
```

Comment: Using the `[adsisearcher]` accelerator as shown here would generally be more preferred than the accepted answer, because you're not instantiating a com object that isn't required, and it uses the conventional syntax for ADSI searches against AD without having to explicitly declare additional constants. It's more accessible to PowerShell users that don't come from a programming background.